# What was the name of the BW comic strip about a boy and his robot?

Tags: story-identification, comics

This line drawing comic strip was in the comic pages of the newspaper, probably the L.A. Times. It was very family-friendly, not horror or scary. It didn't run in circulation very long, maybe less than a year. I'm poor at dating years, but let's say around the 80-90s. I saw it in the newspaper, not as a comic book. Young boy had a friendly relationship with the robot. Line drawings were simple and whimsical, like Charlie Brown.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. In particular, what year did you read this strip? What did the boy look like? What was his name? How did you know that his companion was a robot?

Comment: Without more information,  the only thing I can think of is Calvin and Hobbes.

Comment: Typically, the daily strips were B&W and the ones in the Sunday edition were in color.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Robotman, by Jim Meddick? It later morphed into Robotman and Monty, then just Monty.

But Robotman was about Robotman living with the Milde family. The two boys - one roughly 12 and the other 16 or so - were Oscar and Gary. The 12 year old hung out with Robotman the most.

Comment: No, that was a comic book. I saw this only in a newspaper. I remember only 1 young boy. Not a super-hero style.

Comment: @Steve I recall reading "Robotman and Monty" as a kid in the newspaper. It may have been adapted or compiled in a book, but it was definitely a newspaper comic strip. That said, it doesn't meet the "short run" criteria - wikipedia says it's still going (as "Monty"), and debuted 38 years ago.

Comment: @qazmlpok "Monty Montahue is the protagonist and titular character. He is an odd, optimistic nerd who often comes up with strange inventions and works odd jobs." No--this is not the strip I am referring to.

Comment: Robot man was definitely a newspaper comic strip, and the first years did not feature Monty at all.